# Which data structures are optimal in the following cases

Tags: data-structures

[image: The following image contains the question.]
My answers:

a) queue
b) Directed Graph
c) Hash Table
d) 2D Array
e) Stack
f) Hash Table
g) queue
h) Array
i) Stack
j) No idea

Comment: So what's your question? Can't you look up those answers? If you have questions about specific ones, ask. But don't ask us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd often choose the same data structures as you did, with a few exceptions:
**a)** A heap would sort the programs according to their priority allowing for fast O(1) access to the program with greatest priority
**b)** An undirected graph could be used, since telecommunication is symmetrical
**e)** & **i)** a doubly linked-list would probably be used in a real scenario since it allows for redo/forward functionality, but a stack isn't wrong either
**h)** A linked-list would be better since the size of entries grows constantly
**j)** A directed graph could be used (allowing for directory loops etc.)